# flask doesn't load pictures

Tags: python, html, flask

I have a python script that creates a flask webserver, its code is the following:

```
from flask import Flask
from time import strftime, sleep, localtime
from flask import render_template
import os

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return render_template('home.html')

@app.route("/gallery")
def fill_gallery():
    image_names = os.listdir('./images')
    print('image_names: ',image_names)
    return render_template('gallery.html', image_names=image_names)

if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

I want to upload pictures to a website on my raspberry pi, but the pictures are not displayed correctly.

my gallery.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>

</head>
<body>
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h1 class="page-header">Gallery</h1>
        </div>
        {{image_names}}
        <hr>
        {% for image_name in image_names %}
        <div>
            <img class="img-responsive" src=" {{url_for('fill_gallery', filename=image_name)}}">
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have 4 images in my images folder which names are displayes on the page. But I can only see that little broken picture icon, not the picture themselves. What can be the problem?

Thanks

Comment: This isn't so much a programming question, I think. The most likely issue is simply that the image files are not readable for the web server process.

Comment: pngs, jpgs, the resoultions are different. How can I find a working image?